# Selenium Remote Webdriver - Invalid session ID

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium remote webdriver.

This is an outline on how my code looks:

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor = myip, desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
url = "someurl.com"

def test1(input):
    driver.get(url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    ...
    
def test2(input):
    driver.get(url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    ...
    
def test3(input):
    driver.get(url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    ...
    
def test4(input):
    driver.get(url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    ...
```

In my log, I will see that `test1` and `test2` completed successfully, but for `test3` and `test4` I get the error: `invalid session id` on the `driver.get(url)` lines. All the tests start the same way, and I'm not quitting or closing the driver until the very end (after all tests run).

Is there a reason this is happening?

Comment: are there any exception thrown in any test (driver close in any test)

Comment: No, there are no other exceptions.